# Is there a difference between "@MainActor in" and "MainActor.run"?

Tags: swift, swift-concurrency

Is there any difference between:

```
Task { await MainActor.run { ... } }
```

and

```
Task { @MainActor in ... }
```

Comment: Offhand, I would suspect the first one to create a small task that simply "trampolines" to the main actor, while the second transitions to the main actor directly.  Some time spent in the debugger might verify that.

Answer (score 12):

One difference is that one takes a synchronous closure whereas the other uses an `async` closure. Specifically, [`run`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/mainactor/run(resulttype:body:)) takes a synchronous closure (i.e., the `body` is *not* `async`):

```swift
public static func run<T>(resultType: T.Type = T.self, body: @MainActor @Sendable () throws -> T) async rethrows -> T where T : Sendable
```

This is ideally suited for the scenario where you are on some other actor, but want to run a series of three methods, all of which are isolated to the main actor, but want to do it with a single context switch, not three.

But, in [`Task.init`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/task/init(priority:operation:)-5ltye), the `operation` is `async`, which makes it a slightly more flexible mechanism:

```swift
public init(priority: TaskPriority? = nil, operation: @escaping @Sendable () async -> Success)
```

---

So, to illustrate the difference, consider:

```swift
Task { @MainActor in
    statusText = "Fetching"
    await viewModel.fetchData()
    statusText = "Done"
}
```

But you cannot `await` within `MainActor.run`:

```swift
Task {
    await MainActor.run {            // Cannot pass function of type '@Sendable () async -> ()' to parameter expecting synchronous function type
        statusText = "Fetching"
        await viewModel.fetchData()
        statusText = "Done"
    }
}
```

You would have to insert yet another `Task` inside. (!)

```swift
Task {
    await MainActor.run {
        Task {
            statusText = "Fetching"
            await viewModel.fetchData()
            statusText = "Done"
        }
    }
}
```

I actually use both patterns sparingly, but this is one difference between them.

Comment: FWIW, I find that if the method or property is defined on the correct actor, it largely renders the above patterns moot. The burden should be at the point of definition, not at the call point, IMHO. There are edge cases where these are useful (e.g. to reduce the number of context switches), but often it is just code smell.